# Illegal argument in functor position - possible bracket issue

Tags: common-lisp

I am new to LISP and am trying to develop a few applications. Here I am trying to count the number of occurrences of every element in a list passed to this function. But unfortunately I am getting a " Illegal argument in functor position" error. Can somebody help me solve this and get this program working? Any help would be appreciated

```
       (defun length1 (lst)
             (let ((list1 (remove-duplicates lst)))
             (cond ((null list1) 0)
                  (let ((number (count (car list1) lst)))) 
                  (print "Word was: ") 
                  (print '(car list1)) 
                  (print "Number of Occurances: ") 
                  (print number) 
                  (length (rest lst)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Common Lisp syntax (which appears to be the one used, not Scheme's) this is how it would look:

```
(defun length1 (lst)
  (let ((list1 (remove-duplicates lst)))
    (cond ((null list1) 0)
          (t (let ((number (count (car list1) lst))) 
               (print "Word was: ") 
               (print (car list1)) 
               (print "Number of Occurrences: ") 
               (print number) 
               (length (rest lst)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me understand why the output to my program now is:

"Word was: " 
(CAR LIST1) 
"Number of Occurences: " 
1 
3

Comment: Make sure that you copy the code _exactly_ as above. Other than that, I don't know how are you testing the program, or what's supposed to be the correct output - you determine that.

Comment: I have copied the code as above, still unfortunately been unable to get my desired output. Which would be if i entered "the cat sat on the mat" that the output would be "word was: the number of occurences 2" and like wise fro the other words.

Comment: @Fergo how exactly are you calling it? because if I enter `(length1 '(the cat sat on the mat))` the output is `"Word was: "'the"Number of Occurrences: "2`. It's just a matter of fiddling a bit with `print` and convert the symbols to strings to display them prettier, but in essence is correct.

Comment: From calling (length1 ' (the cat sat on the mat)) it outputs "Word was: " 
CAT 
"Number of Occurrences: " 
1 
5. 
Im using lispworks, if that makes any difference to the potential output?

Comment: @Fergo that is happenning because you're removing duplicates in the list, hence the first `the` gets eliminated and the first word is `cat`. In my Lisp, it's the second `the` the one that gets eliminated, that's why I hadn't noticed the problem.

Comment: oh yes, that makes more sense, so should i remove the 'remove-duplicates' from the code ?

Comment: @Fergo give it a try, it's up to you ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately having no luck with this at all! anytime i remove or change something the program doesn't run...